# How to return value from function that is passed from factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently in the view the `totalCost` is passed as a function to `round`, but it has to be integer value.

**View**

```
{{round(shoppingCart.totalCost)}}
```

**Factory**

```
myApp.factory( ....
var calculateTotalCost = function(){
    return this.items.map(function(item){
      return HelperFunctions.getPrice(item) * item.quantity;
    }).reduce(function(p, c){
      return p + c;
    });
  };
var factory = {
 shoppingCart: {order: currentOrder, totalCost: calculateTotalCost}
}
return factory;
}
```

How to solve it?

```
round : function (value) {
        return typeof value !== 'undefined'? value.toFixed(2): 0;
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you had `totalCost` variable which hold reference of `calculateTotalCost` function there in `shoppingCart` object. So while showing the same variable on view, you need to have service reference make available over the view by doing `$scope.shoppingCart = shoppingCart`

You could use `number` filter itself with precision `2` in your case, as you wanted to make the value fixed to precision `2`. That will also help you to show the number in currency format.

```
{{shoppingCart.totalCost() | number:2 }}
```

Comment: @RCola well, I see your update, It should have `$scope.roud = factory.round` in controller

Comment: Now it works. How pipe filter rounds values? I expect it to work like `number >= 5` then round up; `number < 5` round down.

Comment: @RCola it takes `value` & pass it to `number`(out of the box filter provided by angular) and then it apply passed precision to it. You could use ternary operator to achieve the thing which you wanted.. `{{shoppingCart.totalCost() > 5  ?  | number: (shoppingCart.totalCost() > 5 ? 2: 0) }}`

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid to call a function from a factory directly in a view expression.

In your directive's controller:

1. Inject the factory.
2. Call a function `getTotalCost` (which hides `calculateTotalCost`)
3. Store the result in a variable.
4. Apply the round function directly in the controller could be a nice idea too.
5. Finally bind the variable to the view.

Comment: Is there a way to make Angular handle / update automatically `shoppingCart.totalCost` by calling `calculateTotalCost ` if the `items` changes? I managed to make `calculateTotalCost` get called on `productAdd()` and `productRemove()` but I prefer Angular to handle this.

Comment: Yes with `$scope.$watch('items.length', function () { … })`